# Plasma cleaner Increasing pressure in vacuum

Tags: heat

We have a plasma cleaner, in order for the plasma to be created there has to be around 200-300 mtorr.

As soon as we turn the plasma, the mtorr instantly goes up but the vacuum line is still active.

The question is: What is the plasma in the chamber doing to make the pressure increase?

If this is the wrong section of stacked exchange can someone redirect me to the right section?

Comment: Do you observe the same increase in pressure if a classical McLeod gauge is used? (Caution, some labs officially banned any mercury...) Agreed, 200 mtorr is not the typical working range for a Pirani, but what if the charges or/and frequency generated by the plasma cleaner interfere with the electronics of your pressure sensor?  The nature of the plasma (Argon, Nitrogen, Oxygen; different glow) needn't be the principal cause.

Comment: You can also tell if the militorr is increasing because the plasma turns from purple to white, also at around 500 mtorr the plasma cuts off.